# Should it be "fits" or "fit"?

Tags: verb-forms

I don't know which one of them is correct:

> I was wondering if it fit you
>
> I was wondering if it fits you

Can anyone give some explanations that I could remember for the rest of my life!

Comment: what is "if it sort"? you mean if it is sort etc.

Comment: It is an expression used in conversation!
Example: she sort of looks like you!

Comment: You can remove it without any changes in the meaning! :)

Comment: I made the sentence simpler, take a look at it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main clause of your sentence is "*I was wondering*", and it's in **Past** Continuous tense.  The subordinate clause written in **Present** Indefinite tense would be "*it fit**s** you*" ('it' is the third person singular, so we need an 's' with 'fit').

When you combine the two clauses, you face the decision whether to change the tense of the subordinate clause, or leave it as is.  The decision depends on whether you the fitting of "it" is still unresolved or it has been already (by the time of speaking/writing the sentence) found out.

If the "fitting" of "it" is still unresolved, you can use Present tense in the subordinate clause

> I was wondering if it fit**s** you.  (*fits* = Present tense)

if you already know by "now", then you can put the subordinate clause in the same tense as the main clause:

> I **was** wondering if it **fit** you. (*fit* = Past tense)

I think that in the majority of cases, the entire situation is in the past, so the latter variation is more likely to relate it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is grammatically correct, whereas the second one 
is incorrect.

The past/past participle form of the verb fit is normally fit.  The first sentence is in the past, so the "fit" has been used in the sentence as the past form, not the present form.

If you want to form the sentence in the present, you can use fits as follows:

I am wondering if it fits you.